# Big Query: Get Closest Percentile Value

Tags: google-bigquery, analytics

I have a large table of percentiles generated using the PERCENT_RANK() function within Big Query. The table output generates many rows of data that have percentile numbers that are very close to each other. I am looking to only return 10 rows with values that are closets to the 100th, 90th, 80th, 70th etc. percentiles.

More specifically, I am looking for the number that is closest to the 80th percentile (.8) and have the following sample values:

.81876543
.81123141
.80121214
.80012123
.80001213
.80001112
.79999121

In this case .80001112 is the closest to .8.

Is there a SQL function I can use that only returns the ten values closest to those percentiles.

Comment: Do you want to query the generated table to get 10 rows, or generate percentiles again but this time only have 10 values?

Comment: As a side note, it's recommended to use standard SQL dialect. Maybe the APPROX_QUANTILES function will work for your case?
 https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#approx_quantiles

Answer (score 1):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.percentiles` AS (
  SELECT .81876543 percentile UNION ALL
  SELECT .81123141 UNION ALL
  SELECT .80121214 UNION ALL
  SELECT .80012123 UNION ALL
  SELECT .80001213 UNION ALL
  SELECT .80001112 UNION ALL
  SELECT .79999121 
), targets AS (
   SELECT check
   FROM UNNEST([1, .9, .8, .7, .6, .5, .4, .3, .2, .1]) check
)
SELECT check, ARRAY_AGG(percentile ORDER BY ABS(percentile - check) LIMIT 10) val
FROM `project.dataset.percentiles`
CROSS JOIN targets
WHERE ABS(percentile - check) < .05
GROUP BY check
ORDER BY check
```

above gives you 10 closest values per each percentile - 100%, 90% 80% etc

If you need just one per each - you can check out below query

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.percentiles` AS (
  SELECT .81876543 percentile UNION ALL
  SELECT .81123141 UNION ALL
  SELECT .80121214 UNION ALL
  SELECT .80012123 UNION ALL
  SELECT .80001213 UNION ALL
  SELECT .80001112 UNION ALL
  SELECT .79999121 
), targets AS (
   SELECT check
   FROM UNNEST([1, .9, .8, .7, .6, .5, .4, .3, .2, .1]) check
)
SELECT check, ARRAY_AGG(percentile ORDER BY ABS(percentile - check) LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] val
FROM `project.dataset.percentiles`
CROSS JOIN targets
WHERE ABS(percentile - check) < .05
GROUP BY check
ORDER BY check
```